Fine-Tuned GPT 4o-mini model Is not Calling Tool Using its Prompt Template
I fine-tuned a gpt 4o-mini model using a custom dataset. After I built the agent and the RAG system which is decorated with tool, the model is not calling this tool even if I clearly mentioned in its prompt that calling this tool is a must.
Knowing that the custom dataset does not contain any tool calling examples.
The only way is by provding the tool name as a string as follows:
llm_with_tools = ChatOpenAI(**kwargs).bind_tools(tools=self.tools, tool_choice="func1")
How can I avoid this and keep the desicion of calling the function for the model by referring to the prompt?
